# Sort a dict with month and years as strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
a = {'MAR 96': '274.30', 'MAR 19': '39.05', 'MAR 04': '20.18', 'MAR 73': '20.18'}
```

I want to sort this dictionary in ascending way. How can I do that when months in strings and years added in the string?

Note: Mar 73 means 1973

1. Years start from 1950.
2. 50-99 means 1950 to 1999
3. 00-49 means 2000 to 2049
4. Sep 50 means 1950

Output should be

```
{'MAR 73': '20.18', 'MAR 96': '274.30', 'MAR 04': '20.18', 'MAR 19': '39.05'}
```

Comment: You need to decide more clearly how to deal with the years. What is `25`? Is that `1925` or `2025` and why? Where's the cutoff? Also is your month always `MAR`? It's weird to have a sort example with no variety. And, why are you using a dict if order is important?

Comment: Updated the same in the question. This is how dictionaries are to be sorted by year and month.

Comment: I removed the 3.x and 2.7 tags. The 3.x tag is effectively dead now and 2.7 should only be used if you require a 2.7 solution for maintenance on a codebase you are unable to update.

Comment: Anyway, dictionaries *conceptually do not have an order*. In 3.7+ they remember the order of insertion, but this is an implementation detail.

Comment: That said, the way to sort things according to a custom rule is the same as ever: implement the rule as a "key" function and then pass it to the free `sorted` or the `.sort` method of lists. Thus we are left with the question: what happened when you tried to write code to implement that key function?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Isn't dicts remembering the insertion order a language specification from 3.7 on (and was an implementation detail for CPython 3.6)?

Comment: Right, detail in 3.6, guaranteed in existing versions after that. However, last I checked, my understanding was that they reserve the right to change it back. `OrderedDict` is still around, for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lookup that maps your months to a number (truncated here for simplicity). Then decide a cutoff for the year a century rolls over. Using 50. 49 will be 2049, 50 will be 1950. Then you just need a function that converts your string to tuple, which can be used for sorting. If you are using a version of python that preserves dict ordering, you can pass the sorted `items()` back to `dict()`:

```
a = {'JAN 50': '274.30', 'MAR 49': '274.30', 'APR 19': '19.05', 'MAR 19': '39.05', 'MAR 04': '20.18', 'MAR 73': '20.18'}

def get_sort(s):
    MONTHS = {
        'JAN': 0,
        'FEB': 1,
        'MAR': 2,
        'APR': 3
    }
    CENTURY_BORDER = 50

    mon, year = s[0].split()
    year = int(year)
    
    if year < CENTURY_BORDER: 
        year += 2000
    else:
        year += 1900
        
    return (year, MONTHS[mon])
    
dict(sorted(a.items(), key=get_sort))
```

Result:

```
{'JAN 50': '274.30',
 'MAR 73': '20.18',
 'MAR 04': '20.18',
 'MAR 19': '39.05',
 'APR 19': '19.05',
 'MAR 49': '274.30'}
```

You can see that passing an item into `get_sort()` will return a tuple exactly that you need for sorting:

```
get_sort(("JAN 50", '274.30'))
# (1950, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strptime` to parse the date strings, and use a one liner.

```py
import datetime as dt

a = {'MAR 96': '274.30', 'MAR 19': '39.05', 'MAR 04': '20.18', 'MAR 73': '20.18'}

sorted(a.items(), key=lambda item: dt.datetime.strptime(item[0], '%b %y'))
```

This utilizes on how strptime will parse years, if 2 digits of the year were given.

**Note**: As mentioned in the comments, this will not work for years less than 69. The cutoff for `strptime` is 1969 as per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html).

Comment: This is nice, unfortunately it doesn't give you an option for a year cutoff. The [documented cutoff](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) is 1969.

Comment: Updated answer, adding the documented cutoff for `strptime`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `datetime` module. You'll get an array of tuples, you can convert this to `dict`.

**Note, as of Python version 3.7, dictionaries are ordered. In Python 3.6 and earlier, dictionaries are unordered.**

**Code:**

```
import datetime
a = {'MAR 50': '274.30', 'MAR 96': '274.30', 'MAR 19': '39.05', 'MAR 04': '20.18', 'MAR 73': '20.18'}

def get_key(tup):
    k = tup[0]
    d = int(k.split(' ')[1])
    new_key = '19' + '%02d' % d if d >= 50 else '20' + '%02d' % d
    new_key = k[:-2] + new_key
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(new_key, '%b %Y')


b = sorted(a.items(), key=get_key)
print(b)

print(dict(b))
```

**Output**

```
[('MAR 50', '274.30'), ('MAR 73', '20.18'), ('MAR 96', '274.30'), ('MAR 04', '20.18'), ('MAR 19', '39.05')]

{'MAR 50': '274.30', 'MAR 73': '20.18', 'MAR 96': '274.30', 'MAR 04': '20.18', 'MAR 19': '39.05'}
```